# SQLite to strongly typed dataset

Tags: c#, sqlite, typed-dataset

Скачал из NuGget System.Data.SQLite а connection в creater connection не могу. Отсюда  вытекает проблема не могу создать строго типизированный DataSet. Идеи 2 первая отказаться от строгой типизации и руками заполнить DS, мне она не особо нравится, много букв как то, второй вариант достучатся до api генерации и насильно запустить его на вояв что то вроде библиотеки, если честно нравится еще меньше чем первый вариант. Попахивает любовью к велосипедам. Так что прошу в студию ваше мнение как бороться со сложившейся проблемой? или мне и правда руками набивать DataSet?

Comment: _"не могу создать строго типизированный DataSet"_ -- а он реально нужен? используйте DataAdapter для заполнения DataSet, а потом просто привяжите его к UI.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду по наделать кучу адапатров для каждой таблице и где то ими наполнять DS ?

Comment: для каждой таблицы не нужно. т.к. есть [DataAdapter.Fill(DataSet)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/377a8x4t(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Что то не очень вас понимаю.  Вы предлагаете создать пустой DataSet Создать объектов DataAdapter-ов по количеству таблиц  описать их команды а потом записать работу каждого адпатора в DS  ?

Comment: один DataSet и один DataAdapter, см. [How to fill Dataset with multiple tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345761/how-to-fill-dataset-with-multiple-tables)

Answer (score 1):

Установите `System.Data.SQLite` глобально: добавьте его в GAC, пропишите то, что у вас обычно прописывается в app.config, - в machine.config.

После этого перезапустите студию и тогда вы сможете создать типизированный dataSet через мастер.